# How to read and assign to variable/list multiple text files?

Tags: python

I have multiple files, let's say `data{1..10}.txt` in folder `data/`

I need to read these files into python environment for further use, example code i have in mind is:

```
chr_list = []

x = 0
for item in range(10):
    datafile="data/data"+str(i+1)+".txt"
    chr_list[x] = open(datafile, "r")
    x += 1
```

The expected outcome would be

```
print(chr_list[0])

#prints out content of file data/data1.txt
```

This code doesn't work even after correcting all possible errors. Thus, i would like to see some examples on how to reach my desired outcome.

Comment: You must actually read the file content: `chr_list.append(open(datafile, "r").read())`

Comment: The code still brings out the same errors, so i assume there has to be a deeper mistake in a code

Comment: Sorry, the as the list was originally empty, you must `append` to it. I updated my comment.

Comment: Please take care to always include the complete error traceback in your question when you have an error, it makes it easier to spot the problems in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Thierry Lathuille pointed out, to get the contents of the file you have to actually call the `read` method. Without calling this, you will have a list of open files, not their contents. You can also shorten your code by using the for-loop counter instead of incrementing your own value.

New code:

```
chr_list = []

for x in range(10):
    datafile="data/data"+str(i+1)+".txt"
    chr_list.append(open(datafile).read())
```

**EDIT:**

The error comes from the fact that you can't add  items to a list by referencing a new index - you have to use the `append` method.

**EDIT 2:**

You can also cut down your code by using list comprehensions:

```
chr_list = [open("data/data"+str(i+1)+".txt").read() for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Yeah, both answers solved it. How can i mark both as correct?

Comment: I don't think you can... Does yganalyst's answer actually produce a list of the contents?

Answer (score 1):

It can do with a dictionary not a list.

```py
chr_list = {}

x = 0
for i in range(10):
    datafile="data/data"+str(i+1)+".txt"
    chr_list[x] = open(datafile, "r")
    x += 1
```

```
chr_list[0]
```

#### Or

```py
chr_list = {}

for i in range(10):
    name = "data" + str(i+1)
    chr_list[name] = open("data/"  + name + ".txt", "r")
```

```
chr_list['data1']
```

Comment: Changing [] to {} fixes an issue.

Comment: This code won't currently add the contents of the files to the list/dictionary... It will make a list of file objects.

Comment: When calling chr_list[0] it gives the content of the file though, what am i missing?

Comment: `chr_list[0]` isn't an index when using dictionaries in this way... use `chr_list['data1']` instead... Also, using this code, `chr_list['data1']` gives `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='data1.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`, **not** the content of `data1.txt`...

Comment: You’re not actually reading the contents of the file, nor are you properly handling it using a context manager.